# wso2 EI 611 ActiveMQ

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, wso2-esb

Declared Message store in ESB

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messageStore class="org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore" name="MySQLStockAdjustment" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="store.jms.destination">MySQLStockAdjustment</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.failover.message.store.name">MySQLStockAdjustmentFailover</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.jms.connection.factory">myQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.producer.guaranteed.delivery.enable">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.jms.cache.connection">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.jms.JMSSpecVersion">1.1</parameter>
</messageStore>
```

and I just want for beginning to store the mesage in it and than use a proxy to read messages form it ..

proxy is simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="stockAdjustment" startOnLoad="true" transports="jms" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <!--  get all data -->
            <sequence key="AdjustmentContext"/>
            <filter regex="MySQL" source="$ctx:StockSource">
                <then>
                    <iterate expression="//request">
                        <target>
                            <sequence>
                                <property expression="//qty" name="qty" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                                <property expression="//code" name="code" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                                <log level="custom">
                                    <property expression="fn:concat('parmams:Code: ' ,$ctx:code, ' ;Qty: ',$ctx:qty)" name="info"/>
                                </log>
                                <call blocking="true">
                                    <endpoint key="StockAdjustmentEp"/>
                                </call>
                            </sequence>
                        </target>
                    </iterate>
                </then>
                <else/>
            </filter>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>

        </faultSequence>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">MySQLStockAdjustment</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">myQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
</proxy>
```

so when I send a data message trough Postman Im getting the following:

WARN {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils} -  Can't determine size of JMS message; unsupported message type : org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils}
 ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.BaseUtils} -  Unsupported JMS message type org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.BaseUtils}
 ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageReceiver} -  Unknown error processing message {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageReceiver}

message is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <StockAdjRequest>
            <source>MySQL</source>
            <request><qty>2</qty><code>PR2</code></request>
            <request><qty>2</qty><code>PR2</code></request>
            <request><qty>2</qty><code>PR2</code></request>
            </StockAdjRequest>
            </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I see that message ended in queue but I can't read it trough ActiveMQ  web console ...

I documentation I found that maybe a proble that I need to "...If you are using ActiveMQ 5.12.2 and above when working with message stores, you need to set the following system property on server start up for the JMS message store of the ESB Profile to work as expected.

-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES="*" ...."

BUt I dont found HOW to do it ... can anyone help me ?

Comment: So far I figure out that error is on ActiveMQ and Message Store relation. When I put a message directly to queue trough proxy it works BUT using Message storage and using API to put message there is NOT ...

Answer (score 1):

When you store a message in a JMS queue defining a messageStore and using store mediator, you don't just store the "textual" payload from the message, but the entire java MessageContext object is serialized and store as a binary message in the queue.

To read such a message, you need to use a message processor, you can't read it with a simple JMS proxy or even jms inbound endpoint.

And you can't read it with ActiveMQ console because it can't deserialize it

Comment: My problem is if Im saving storing message direct with Endpoints and Im pointing proxy to consume that message it works. BUT when I store message in sequence just simply put the name of message store ,, message is stored but after it my proxy cannot read message .. it gives me error  ' Can't determine size of JMS message; unsupported message type : org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage '

Comment: Yes, this is because when you store a message with an endpoint, you store the "text" payload. But using store mediator, you store a serialized java object that require a MessageProcessor to be deserialized : you can't read such a message with a proxy...

Comment: Have a look to https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Store+and+Forward+Using+JMS+Message+Stores

Comment: It look like this would be that good one .. let me check tonight

Comment: ERROR {org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsConsumer} -  [SalesOrder-C-1] cannot receive message from store. Error:Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.commons.StorableMessage! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes. {org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsConsumer}

Comment: this is what I got ..I follow the sugestions ..create a mesage store and used message processor ...but ...is this a know issue ?